# Basis of line in vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I puzzled by the following question I found in *Linear Algebra and its Applications* by Gilbert Strang:

> Find a counterexample to the following statement: If $v_1$ , $v_2$ , $v_3$, $v_4$ is a basis for the vector space $\Bbb R^4$, and if **W** is a subspace, then some subset of the $v$’s is a basis for **W**.

The answer in the book is:

> Let $v_1 = (1, 0, 0, 0)$, ... , $v_4 = (0, 0, 0, 1)$ be the coordinate vectors. If **W** is the line through $(1, 2, 3, 4)$, none of the $v$'s are in **W**.

However, **W** $\in \Bbb R^4$ and therefore should belong to the span of $v$, by definition. In the counterexample he provides, **W** is achieved by the linear combination $v_1 + 2v_2 + 3v_3 + 4v_4$. So, why is $v$ not a basis for W?

I don't know what I am missing here.

Comment: Part of the definition of "basis for $W$" is that it consists of elements of $W$.

Comment: **W** is not an element of the vector space, but a subset.

Answer (score 1):

The assertion $\mathbf W\in\mathbb R^4$ is false. *Each* element of $\mathbf W$ is an element of $\mathbb R^4$, but $\mathbf W$ is a *subset* of $\mathbb R^4$.

And remember that in order that a set $B$ is a basis of $\mathbf W$, $B$ must be a *subset* of $\mathbf W$.